# NetworkInterface, Wifi or Lan?

Tags: c#

How do i find out if a NetworkInterface is a Wifi or Lan Card in C#?
And is there a safe way of determining this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [NetworkInterfaceType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.networkinterfacetype.aspx) property of the [NetworkInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.aspx) class.

It will be equal to `NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211` if the interface represents a WiFi adapter.

Comment: Yes, i tried that om my Win7 and it worked, but it didn't work on a Windows XP. Any workaround?

Comment: It works in XP SP3 (and XP SP2 x64). Maybe you can upgrade your system?

Comment: Hmmm, ok, is there a workaround? Maybe WMI or something like that?

Comment: @Fredefl, indeed, you can use the `AdapterTypeID` member of the [Win32_NetworkAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class.

Comment: Ok, id didn't work with AdapterType. Is there a difference between AdapterType & AdapterTypeID?

Comment: As far as I know, `AdapterTypeID` is an integer (`9` for WiFi) and `AdapterType` is a string (`"Wireless"` for WiFi).

Comment: It just said Ethernet 802.3 for the wifi card. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, maybe that feature is not even available at the WMI level before SP3. What does `ipconfig` say about the interface?

Comment: It's under it's own tab called "Wireless" or something like that.

Comment: Actually, I was referring to the [ipconfig](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ipconfig.mspx?mfr=true) command-line tool :)

Comment: Yesyes, Wireless Lan Card Connection or something like that (My cmd is in Danish soooo...)

Comment: @Fredefl, then I can only suggest to spawn an `ipconfig` process and parse its output. Of course, as you already know, that output is language-dependent, so that solution probably won't work on all Windows locale, and may even break on the same machine if Windows is updated or if a LIP is installed. Is upgrading to SP3 really out of the question? :)

Comment: Yes, because this work is preparing the machine for SP3 :D But, maybe there is another option. Maybe i could test if the Wfi cards name contained something like this:<br>

Comment: Wifi, 802.11 ? Maybe that is an option?

Comment: *Maybe* `Wireless`. I don't know if all the manufacturers really want to have `802.11` in their products' display names. Of course, that will match `Infrared Wireless` too, so you might get false positives.

Comment: I need the lan card and not the wifi card :D

Comment: Okay, false negatives then, assuming your users don't have IEEE 1394 interfaces :)

Comment: I don't think they have ;D Thanks for the help anyways! :D :D :D