# C# detecting WiFi network interface?

Tags: c#

In C# how do we detect that a particular NetworkInterface is a WiFi interface ?

I am using following call to enumerate the interfaces, but have to detect which ones of them is the wireless interface

```
         public static NetworkInterface[] GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200850/networkinterface-wifi-or-lan

Comment: @FLCL strangely, the docs say only a subset of the enumeration is returned.

Comment: @Gusdor, if you about http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.networkinterfacetype.aspx so yes sometimes stackoverflow better than msdn:)

Comment: @FLCL i bounced straight over there to check as `NetworkInterface` tells you a lot. Imagine my surprise!